# Lag Function - Create Dummy Row for Last Value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I can't share code or specifics, so hopefully this general question/example makes sense.

The Next Due Date field is a physical field in the system; however, the Due Date field is not.  For Due Date, I'm using the LAG function in SQL Server 2012 to "copy" the Next Due Date from the previous row.  It is working properly, but I'm wondering if I can create a dummy row to capture the last row's Next Due Date?

In the example below, you'll see that rows 1, 2 and 3 are working properly, as the table contains actual data, i.e. TestID.

My ask:  Is there anyway to fabricate a row (in this example, row 4), so I can capture the next due date of 2/25/2020 (and location of New York), even though data (TestID) does not currently exist in the table yet?

```
Row   TestID    Test Location     Due Date       Next Due Date
1     123       New York          02/05/2018*    10/13/2018
2     456       New York          10/13/2018     06/20/2019
3     789       New York          06/20/2019     02/25/2020
-------------------------------------------------------------------
4     n/a       New York          02/25/2020     n/a

*calculated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what `lag()` has to do with this.  You seem to want:

```
select TestID, TestLocation, DueDate, NextDueDate
from t
union all
select null, TestLocation, max(nextDueDate) as dueDate, null as NextDueDate
from t
group by TestLocation;
```

Note that I've left the extra values as `NULL`, so you don't have to deal with mixing string and non-string types.

Comment: I have to use lag because the field DueDate is not an actual field.  However, your suggestion of using a union with the max Next Inspection Date may work for this solution!  Thanks so much!